# nginx proxy adding servlet path

Tags: tomcat, nginx, spring-security

I have Tomcat 6 running web application on path "be". Spring security is used for login process. Login URL is `/console/login` and it redirects to `/console/customer` after login. I use https for `login` url and http for `customer` URL. I do not specify servlet path in any spring configuration files. All works fine and after accessing `/be/console/login` correct redirect (to `/be/console/customer`) received.

Now I want to have a proxy. I configured Nginx to forward `https://localhost` to `https://<someip>:9443` and the same for http, to forward from port 80 to port 9080.

The problem is that Nginx is returning invalid redirect to the browser. Instead `/be/console/customer` it returns `/be/be/console/customer`. Servlet path is added to the URL twice.

How can that second 'be' may be removed?

Thanks.

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl                  on;        
    ssl_certificate      C:\jc\\nginx\\tc\selfsigned.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:\jc\\nginx\\tc\private.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_pass              https://<some ip>:9443;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    } 

    location ~ /.+ {
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_pass              https://<some ip>:9443;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }   
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log  logs/access.log;
    error_log  logs/error.log;

    location / {                
            proxy_redirect          off;
            #server_name_in_redirect    off;
            proxy_pass              http://<some ip>:9080;              
            proxy_set_header        X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    } 

    location ~ /.+ {
            proxy_redirect          off;                
            proxy_pass              http://<some ip>:9080;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working in production:

```
location /demo/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```

Comment: proxy_pass_request_headers is on by default and the rest (of the different param) is just performance related configuration. So the problem is far more complicated.